# Trying to concatenate database name in connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to concatenate database name in connection string like this:

```
public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
        {

        base.Initialize(name, config);

        string connectionString = "Server=My-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Database="+name+";Integrated Security=True; App=EntityFramework;";
        FieldInfo connectionStringField = GetType().BaseType.GetField("_sqlConnectionString", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        connectionStringField.SetValue(this, connectionString);
        }
```

But it throws exception: login failed for the database.
When I hard code the database name it works:

```
string connectionString = "Server=My-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; 
Database=mydb;Integrated Security=True; App=EntityFramework;";
```

Anyone please guide me what am doing wrong.

Thanx

**EDIT:**

I have also tried this:

```
`string domaniName = Helpers.RouteManager.GetSubDomain();
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
sqlBuilder["Data Source"] = "MY-PC\\SQLEXPRESS";
sqlBuilder["Initial Catalog"] = domaniName+"_db";
sqlBuilder["Integrated Security"] = true;
sqlBuilder["Application Name"] = "EntityFramework";`
```

but still getting the same result. When i hardcode dbname it works fine.

Please guide me.

Thanx.

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint and see the value of `connectionString`?

Comment: Yes i did. . it appears to be correct connection string.

Comment: Really? Are you sure the value of `connectionString` is `"Server=My-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; 
Database=mydb;Integrated Security=True; App=EntityFramework;"` when `name` is set to `mydb` and it's concatenated?

Comment: may be name is NULL??

Comment: Here is connection string after concatenation:
Server=My-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=mydb;Integrated Security=True; App=EntityFramework"

Comment: Why aren't you just using the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?? It would cover all of what you're trying to do - and more!